# content-rich button collapsed into icon and show nav tab content

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to achieve this "effect" or whatever its called.
Where I have a content-rich vertically aligned buttons (with an icon, header text, and normal text).

Then when a button gets pressed, A new set of vertically aligned buttons (with an icon and normal text) appeared as new options.

Then when a "sub-button" gets pressed, A content area appears.

I tried "vertically aligned tabs with bootstrap 4" but I'm stuck with:

- showing ONLY the main buttons with full content
- showing ONLY the icon for the main button (where the rest of the button content gets hidden after the click) +and+ the sub-buttons
- return to normal, where only the main buttons appear with full content

as the picture below

[image: Goal]

I'm using: Bootstrap 4 + I know a little of JS

Please help me with this, or guide me to where I could get an answer for it. Thanks

~ update: here is a link for a very basic "vertical navs pills" I'm working on https://codepen.io/bixet/pen/yxGrLO

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Main<br>Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Main<br>Profile</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Main<br>Messages</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Main<br>Settings</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-4">
    <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-subhome-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-subhome" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-subhome" aria-selected="true">SubHome</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-subprofile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-subprofile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-subprofile" aria-selected="false">SubProfile</a>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="col-4">
    <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-subhome" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-subhome-tab">1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque at ex viverra, maximus ante nec, porta turpis. Fusce eu velit nec sem blandit aliquet. Curabitur vitae ultrices leo. Fusce risus mauris, iaculis vitae viverra in, lacinia quis lacus.</div>

      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-subprofile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-subprofile-tab">2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque at ex viverra, maximus ante nec, porta turpis. Fusce eu velit nec sem blandit aliquet. Curabitur vitae ultrices leo. Fusce risus mauris, iaculis vitae viverra in, lacinia quis lacus.</div>      

    </div>
  </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-4">
    <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-subhome2-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-subhome2" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-subhome2" aria-selected="true">SubHome</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-subprofile2-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-subprofile2" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-subprofile2" aria-selected="false">SubProfile</a>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="col-4">
    <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-subhome2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-subhome2-tab">1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque at ex viverra, maximus ante nec, porta turpis. Fusce eu velit nec sem blandit aliquet. Curabitur vitae ultrices leo. Fusce risus mauris, iaculis vitae viverra in, lacinia quis lacus.</div>

      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-subprofile2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-subprofile2-tab">2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque at ex viverra, maximus ante nec, porta turpis. Fusce eu velit nec sem blandit aliquet. Curabitur vitae ultrices leo. Fusce risus mauris, iaculis vitae viverra in, lacinia quis lacus.</div>      

    </div>
  </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">3) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque at ex viverra, maximus ante nec, porta turpis. Fusce eu velit nec sem blandit aliquet. Curabitur vitae ultrices leo. Fusce risus mauris, iaculis vitae viverra in, lacinia quis lacus.</div>

      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">4) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque at ex viverra, maximus ante nec, porta turpis. Fusce eu velit nec sem blandit aliquet. Curabitur vitae ultrices leo. Fusce risus mauris, iaculis vitae viverra in, lacinia quis lacus.</div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you edit to include the solutions you've tried so far?

Comment: done, I just did the sub-level. Still can't know how to do the auto-show or auto-hide or what is called so I could look for it.

Answer (score 1):

i have the following solution that uses pure CSS and some Javascript code :
(See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q50mr9yj/2/)) for a good preview

```js
let menuItems =document.querySelectorAll(".y-menu-item");
menuItems.forEach((item)=>{
    item.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        document.querySelectorAll(".y-texts-wrapper,.y-menu-sublevel-1").forEach((txtw)=>{
            txtw.style.display='none';
        });
        
        item.children[2].style.display='block'
        
    })
})

/********************** */

let subMenuItems=document.querySelectorAll('.y-menu-item-sublevel-1');


subMenuItems.forEach((subItem)=>{
    subItem.addEventListener("click",function(){
      
        document.querySelectorAll(".y-sub-l1-ht,.y-content").forEach((ht)=>{
            ht.style.display='none';
        });
        subItem.children[2].style.display='block'
     
    });
})
```

```css
body{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Montserrat,sans-serif;
    color:#333;
}
p{
    font-size: 10pt;
}
.y-menu{
    padding: 20px;
    height: 80%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
   
}

.y-menu-item{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    border-radius:5px;
    /* background: #eee; */
    cursor: pointer;

}



.y-icon{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: #4E0BEF;
}

.y-s-icon{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;

}
.y-texts-wrapper{
    margin-left: 20px;
    /* display: none; */
}

.y-normaltxt{
    width: 200px;

}
.y-menu-sublevel-1{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 84px;
    margin-top: 47px;
}

.y-menu-item-sublevel-1{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    align-items: center;
    margin:0 0 10px 10px ;
}

@keyframes anim1{
    0% {width: 0;height: 0;opacity: 0;}
    50% {width: 250px;height: 250px;opacity: .5;}
    100% {width: 500px;height: 500px;opacity: 1;}
    
}

.y-content{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    top:20px;
    left:180px;
    padding:20px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #4E0BEF;
    position: fixed;
    display:none;
    text-align: center;
    animation: anim1 .1s ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Menu</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main-menu" class="y-menu">
        <div class="y-menu-item" >
            <div class="y-icon"></div>
            <div class="y-texts-wrapper">
                <h4 class="y-headtxt">Some head text</h4>
                <p class="y-normaltxt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
                
            </div>
            <div class="y-menu-sublevel-1">
                <div class="y-menu-item-sublevel-1">
                    <div class="y-icon y-s-icon"></div>
                    <h4 class="y-headtxt y-sub-l1-ht">Some head text 1</h4>
                    <div class="y-content">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed mollitia et labore sunt distinctio laboriosam numquam laborum doloribus ex animi at amet maiores, quaerat temporibus, exercitationem minima repellat quos eligendi!</div>
                    
                </div> 
                <div class="y-menu-item-sublevel-1">
                    <div class="y-icon y-s-icon"></div>
                    <h4 class="y-headtxt y-sub-l1-ht">Some head text 1</h4>
                    <div class="y-content">The main content</div>

                </div>   
                <div class="y-menu-item-sublevel-1">
                    <div class="y-icon y-s-icon"></div>
                    <h4 class="y-headtxt y-sub-l1-ht">Some head text 1</h4>
                    <div class="y-content">The main content</div>

                </div>                    
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="y-menu-item">
            <div class="y-icon"></div>
            <div class="y-texts-wrapper">
                <h4 class="y-headtxt">Some head text</h4>
                <p class="y-normaltxt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
                
            </div>
            <div class="y-menu-sublevel-1">
                <div class="y-menu-item-sublevel-1">
                    <div class="y-icon y-s-icon"></div>
                    <h4 class="y-headtxt y-sub-l1-ht">Some head text 1</h4>
                    <div class="y-content">The main content</div>
                </div> 
                <div class="y-menu-item-sublevel-1">
                    <div class="y-icon y-s-icon"></div>
                    <h4 class="y-headtxt y-sub-l1-ht">Some head text 1</h4>
                    <div class="y-content">The main content</div>
                </div>   
                <div class="y-menu-item-sublevel-1">
                    <div class="y-icon y-s-icon"></div>
                    <h4 class="y-headtxt y-sub-l1-ht">Some head text 1</h4>
                    <div class="y-content">The main content</div>
                </div>                    
            </div>
            
            
        </div>
        <div class="y-menu-item">
            <div class="y-icon"></div>
            <div class="y-texts-wrapper">
                <h4 class="y-headtxt">Some head text</h4>
                <p class="y-normaltxt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
                
            </div>
            <div class="y-menu-sublevel-1">
                <div class="y-menu-item-sublevel-1">
                    <div class="y-icon y-s-icon"></div>
                    <h4 class="y-headtxt y-sub-l1-ht">Some head text 1</h4>
                    <div class="y-content">The main content</div>
                </div> 
                <div class="y-menu-item-sublevel-1">
                    <div class="y-icon y-s-icon"></div>
                    <h4 class="y-headtxt y-sub-l1-ht">Some head text 1</h4>
                    <div class="y-content">The main content</div>
                </div>   
                <div class="y-menu-item-sublevel-1">
                    <div class="y-icon y-s-icon"></div>
                    <h4 class="y-headtxt y-sub-l1-ht">Some head text 1</h4>
                    <div class="y-content">The main content</div>
                </div>                    
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="y-menu-item">
            <div class="y-icon"></div>
            <div class="y-texts-wrapper">
                <h4 class="y-headtxt">Some head text</h4>
                <p class="y-normaltxt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
                
            </div>
            <div class="y-menu-sublevel-1">
                <div class="y-menu-item-sublevel-1">
                    <div class="y-icon y-s-icon"></div>
                    <h4 class="y-headtxt y-sub-l1-ht">Some head text 1</h4>
                    <div class="y-content">The main content</div>
                </div> 
                <div class="y-menu-item-sublevel-1">
                    <div class="y-icon y-s-icon"></div>
                    <h4 class="y-headtxt y-sub-l1-ht">Some head text 1</h4>
                    <div class="y-content">The main content</div>
                </div>   
                <div class="y-menu-item-sublevel-1">
                    <div class="y-icon y-s-icon"></div>
                    <h4 class="y-headtxt y-sub-l1-ht">Some head text 1</h4>
                    <div class="y-content">The main content</div>
                </div>                    
                
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, bro, your solution is very good for going forward. But the only thing wrong with it is when I try to switch or go to another group. I mean the text should appear back if I want to see a different element. but thanks though :)